# What is a word to describe the standards that people in the business community just know?

Tags: terminology

For instance, tonight I was trying to calculate my gross salary for unemployment and I got the calculation wrong because I didn't know if the start and end date of the pay period was inclusive or not (on both ends).

Business people just know this stuff, and I don't know what it is called.

Comment: “Domain specific knowledge”? Or are you looking for a more specific term?

Comment: @Laurel a more specific term; basically so I can look for the term and learn about it.  I keep thinking it has something to do with "business math" but it's almost like they don't call it anything.

Comment: Could this question be reformulated as: What is a single word that means **common knowledge among business people**?

Comment: People have **working pratice**.

Comment: Maybe you’re thinking of ***convention***?

Comment: 'Business jargon' is probably usable, but it implies (as in other domains do 'BrE' and 'literary' etc) that the English terminology / set of other usages is invariant throughout the 'business world'. You want the relevant style guide, containing the precising/stipulative definitions being used. They may be different from those used by the company across the block.

Comment: I sincerely believe there's no such term.

Either way, it wouldn't apply to anything like gross salary for  unemployment and certainly not to whether the start or end dates of a pay or invoice period were inclusive on either end - those do use special terms precisely because people "just know" they're not the norm or common practice, but change from case to case.

It also wouldn't apply to "business math(s)" which covers areas such as percentage and return on investment.

Comment: **Experience** *I had no idea how to calculate the dates, but John, who runs a business, knows how to do it through experience.*

Comment: @Jim I second that. As a different example from the question, I have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention, which tells you how many days there are in a month and in a year for interest calculation purposes. There are different ones.